# C++ 11 conditional template alias to function

Tags: c++, c++11, function-templates, template-aliases

In C++ 11, I want to make a template alias with two specializations that resolve to a different function each.

```
void functionA();
void functionB();

template<typename T = char>
using Loc_snprintf = functionA;

template<>
using Loc_snprintf<wchar_t> = functionB;
```

So I can call e.g. `Loc_snprintf<>()` and it's resolve to `functionA()`.

Apparently seems impossible (to compile). Is there something ultimately simple that mimics it (maybe using a class template)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 it's not really possible to create aliases of specializations. You must create actual specializations:

```
template<typename T = char>
void Loc_snprintf()
{
    functionA();
}

template<>
void Loc_snprintf<wchar_t>()
{
    functionB();
}
```

With C++14 it would be possible to use [variable templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) to create a kind of alias.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned `using` is for types and unfortunately variable templates are only available in C++14.

Something that is perhaps closest to your initial approach using specialization is using a class template to store a function pointer to one of the two functions:

```
void functionA();
void functionB();

template <typename T = char>
struct Loc_snprintf {
    static constexpr void(*call)(void) = functionA;
};

template <>
struct Loc_snprintf<char> {
    static constexpr void(*call)(void) = functionB;
};
```